# The requested theme does not exist

Tags: php

Help, I'm lost :(
My site was hacked and I was investigating the issue (see the code below)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+/([0-9]{1,7})([a-zA-Z0-9]{4})[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+/$ index.php?smsite=$2&smid=$1 [L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

I removed the second line and the site had stopped working
I returned back the same file, and now it doesn't work at all
And I get the following message:
The requested theme does not exist

The site is hosted with AWS
The theme is located in not were you were expecting it to be
instead of root domain/wp-content/themes
you can find it at root domain/themename/etc.

Besides changing and taking back the file, I haven't change anything
Please advice

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```